# How to assign value to union in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

There is an `union` in C and embedded into C++ as below:

```
typedef union MyUnion MyUnion_;
union MyUnion{
    ULONG   mLong;
    char    mChar;
...
};
```

When I trying to init it like:

```
MyUnion_ test;
test = (MyUnion_)NULL;
```

this is can compile by Mingw32, but gives

```
error: C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'MyUnion_'
```

in VC++ (VS2015). So how to do cast & initialize of `union` in VC++ compiler?

Now I am doing like this:

```
MyUnion_ test;
test.mLong = NULL;
```

but this makes the program look bad when passing union as a parameter.

```
void test(MyUnion_ u)

ULONG i = 0;

// mingw32
test((MyUnion_)i);

// vc++
MyUnion_ temp;
temp.mLong = i;
test(temp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a compiler that supports the C++11 uniform initialization syntax you can use a braced initializer with a single value which will be used to initialize the first non-static field of the union  …

```
MyUnion test{ 0 };
```

You could use `NULL` instead of zero in the code above but it seems confusing to initialise `mLong` (which is a `ULONG`) with `NULL`.

You can also use braced initialization in an assignment statement if you have to set the variable after it was declared …

```
MyUnion test{ 0 };

// ...

test = { 3 };
```

*Note that the braced initializer syntax may also be available in older compilers that offer experimental support for what used to be called C++0x*

Visual Studio 2015 C++ supports braced initializers unless you are compiling a file with a `.c` extension or are using the `/TC` [switch to compile as C code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type) (rather than C++ code).

### Older C++ (and C) compilers

When using compilers that don't support braced initialization the older assignment initialization syntax can be used in declarations ...

```
MyUnion_ test = { 0 };
```

… but not in assignment statements.

### Casting to union type

According to [this IBM Knowledge Center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVUN6_1.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp11.zlinux.doc/language_ref/cplr188.html) casting to a union type is an extension to C99 "... implemented to facilitate porting programs developed with GNU C" - which suggests it's not standard C.

This [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/type-cast-conversions) indicates there are no legal casts **in C** for a union, struct or array.

In **C++** a cast to a union type is possible if a suitable constructor exists...

```
union MyUnion {
   unsigned long   mLong;
   char            mChar;

   MyUnion(unsigned long val) { mLong = val; };
};


// valid cast 
test = (MyUnion)3ul;

// invalid cast - no suitable constructor exists
void * ptr = 0;
test = (MyUnion)ptr;
```

Comment: Hi @Jiu, sorry this reply was so slow, it took me a while to spin up a Visual Studio 2015 environment.  The syntax above compiles for me in Visual Studio 2015 C++.  Do you have the `Compile as C Code (/TC)` option set for the file or project you tried the code above in?

Comment: Thanks! `MyUnion test = { 0 };` is works now. But I still wonder how to make ulong directly cast to union instead using a temp variable like gcc.

Comment: In C++ you can create a constructor to allow a ulong to cast to a union.  In Microsoft C you can't do anything it's not legal.  I've updated my answer to deal with those points.

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor?

```
typedef union MyUnion MyUnion_;
union MyUnion {
    ULONG   mLong;
    char    mChar;
    MyUnion(): mLong(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyUnion_ temp;
    return 0;
}
```